# Calling WebAPI in UnitTest TestInitialize

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

im trying to write a UnitTest for a WebAPI and EF

Im trying to add Data do the database in den TestInitialize, but it didnt work. When i do the same command in a Console Applications, it works.
Is there a different in calling that webapi for tests?

```
 [TestInitialize]
 public void CreateEntityObjects()
 {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:60609/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    Department dep1 = new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "IT" };
    client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Department", dep1);
 }
```

Edit:
So i still just do the initialize no cleanup (later). I was looking manually if there is some data in the database. But no data, no Error, nothing.

Comment: `but it didnt work` is probably the worst problem description in the whole visible universe. What does this mean?

Comment: I'm new to UnitTesting and just want to look if i can add data to my database in the TestInitialize. But it didnt work, i got no data in the database, no error, nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try looking at the result property of the request:

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Department", dep1).Result;
```

and then look at what does the server return:

```
string responseContent = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Now analyze the responseContent variable to see what possible error message you might have gotten from the server. Also you probably want to [`self-host your Web API`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api) in the unit test before sending an HTTP request to it, otherwise your API might not even be started.

Comment: Of course you could use the [`TestContext.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Or simply put a breakpoint on that line and run your test in debug mode which will allow you to inspect the value of the `responseContent` variable.

Comment: Oh tank you, i did it and he said created... I think the problem was the missed .Result? When i call it again without .Result he didnt create data, when i call it with .Result he did. Thank you, fixed